# Is there a cleaner way to represent a parent path from a filesystem URL?

Tags: java, url, path, filesystems, uri

I have an source path which I receive as a filesystem URL from which I want to resolve to an absolute path two parents above; the final type as a `Path` object is desired. To do this I have to convert it to a `URI`, then to a `Path`, and then call `getParent()` on it twice.

Is there a cleaner way to perform this such that I can perform some transformation on either the `URL`, `URI`, or `Path` with a relative string `../..`? I've always found that multiple invocations of `getParent()` to transverse a path to be less intuitive to read at a glance than to provide a relative path with `../`, etc.

```
// Example file system path as a URL
URL u = new URL("file:///a/b/c");

// Must convert to URI and then call 'getParent()' twice
Path p = Paths.get(u.toURI()).getParent().getParent();
```

Comment: Honestly, that’s the best way to do it that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the URL variable anywhere else, then you can skip the conversion like so:

    `p = Paths.get(new URI("file:///a/b/c")).getParent().getParent();`

Now, this next part could be seen as more complicated than it needs to be, but if you just need the folder name, you could do a .getName(0) instead of the two .getParent()'s. However, this does not include the root when you print it out, and it might not meet your needs.

I hope this helps.